# Update ListView even if its adapter is null

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I want to update my list even if the adapter is `null`, but I dont know how to do it.

When I execute the following code my app crashes:

```
ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(context, R.layout.listrow, yal);
if(adapter.getCount()>0){
   lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}else{
   lv.setAdapter(null);
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
lv.invalidateViews();
```

Comment: Does lv.setAdapter(null); set the adapter to null?  If so, is the second to last line throwing a null pointer exception?  Can you show us the log file?

Comment: If the adapter is null or empty, you don't have a list. so what's there to update?

Comment: i delete 1 item from the list so there is none left it schould show an empty list but my app crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adapter is sort of the data source for the list. It provides the individual list items. You can't have a list without an adapter, since then you won't have rows in the list.

Check out the [ListView documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) for more information.

Comment: thats the point i want to update my list 
but on the list there is still 1 item which schouldnt be there so i want to update mylist without reloading the activity

Comment: That's not the question here. You ask how to update a list that has a null adapter. If you want to update the list, then provide a new adapter, or change the items in the current one, then call datasetChanged. **Don't** set the adapter to null. That causes the crash.

Comment: the problem is that when my adapter has no items in it my app crashes

Comment: No, from the code you provided, the app crashes when your adapter has no items because you set the ListView adapter to null - `lv.setAdapter(null);`. You shouldn't do that. A ListView needs an adapter.

Comment: OK, so you have another problem now. I can't do your work for you. Especially when you don't provide error logs and extra code from the adapter. From your comment I get it that you applied my answer, so either accept my answer or look for other solutions elsewhere.

Comment: well this wont work but thanks for trying to help me i think i will google a bit more i think this is more of an understanding problem in general with adapters etc i thought its an standart beginners error

Comment: ok now i know what was wrong my List<Object> yal was null so the adapter was null and all crashed

Answer (score 0):

Don't nullify the adapter - the listView always needs one. Instead, nullify the *dataset* the adapter works with and make sure `getCount()` returns `0` if the dataset is null (or empty). Or don't nullify the dataset, but make it an empty list or array.

If your data changes, update the adapters dataset and call notifyDatasetChanged() on the adapter. Do not create a new adapter for the ListView when you get new data. This is important for several reasons; e.g. the listViews position won't jump to the top but stay where it is.

Example:

```
ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(context, R.layout.listrow, null);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

later

```
adapter.setData(newData);
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```